# Подключение к com порту

Tags: передача-данных, rs232, коммутатор

Имееется оборудование: [свитч](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/163/3com-Superstack-3.html?page=16#manual) 3com 4200, необходимо подключится к нему консольным кабелем для настройки. В мануале сказано, что он сам определяет скорость подключения, 8 бит дата и 1 стоп бит. Под консольником указана дефолтная скорость 119200. 
При попытке подключения к оборудованию, даже напрямую к ком порту компьютера с данными настройками ответа нет. Подключался и через putty и с помощью minicom, так же пробовал перебирать разные скорости. 
Сам свитч физически линкуется, правда сети не выдаёт (скорее всего настроена неизвестная мне подсеть) соответственно через веб не пробиться так же.
Есть ли утилита для автоопределения скорости подключения? Чтобы понять наверняка живое оборудование или нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Попробуйте сначала втыкать консольный кабель и устанавливать параметры порта, а уже потом включать свитч.
2. У свитчей чаще встречается набор параметров 9600-8-N-1. Вообще, 8-N-1 — оно практически всегда и везде так, можно только поперебирать скорости. Flow control почти всегда должен быть выключен, и CTS/RTS, и XON/XOFF.
3. Посмотрите на кабель. Вполне вероятно, что TX и RX (2 и 3 контакты) перекрещены, когда этого не должно быть. Или наоборот, неперекрещены, а оборудование почему-то сделано под нуль-модем. Попробуйте поменять распайку.

Comment: Спасибо, по первому пункту попробую сделать так. Сам кабель точно исправный, подключал им другое оборудование. И еще тогда пояснение, есть хардверный flow control, есть софтверный, выключать их оба?

Comment: Выключать оба. То, что "кабель исправный", ничего не значит. Он может быть исправным, но не таким. Я, кста, почитал за вас мануал по свитчу. На странице 39 явно указано, что должен быть нуль-модемный кабель, на стр. 69 приведена его распайка (для 9-пинового порта): TX и RX должны быть перекрещены. На стр. 40 указаны параметры порта: 19200, 8N1, no hardware flow ctrl. То есть рекомендую начать с п.3, а не с п.1

Comment: я честно его читал, видимо пропустил. спасибо.